# Show uniform convergence 3

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'd like to show that the function series sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^x}$ converges uniformly on every interval of [$\alpha$,$\infty$) when $\alpha>1$. I've tried to do this with Weierstrass' M test, and by the regular and Cauchy definitions but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: You sure about the Weirstrass M test not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M test works. The terms are all less than $\frac{\log(n)}{n^{\alpha}}$ and that sum converges for $\alpha > 1.$

Comment: Sorry, my bad..